# Combine (hour, minute, am/pm) columns for two times, then calculate minutes elapsed

Tags: excel, time, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I have Time In and Time Out that need to be input on a google sheet. It has to be tracked down to the minute so I have a column for hour, minute, and am/pm. My goal is to have the amount of minutes elapsed between the time in and time out in a row.

I have not found a way to combine all three columns into a time, especially with the am/pm column in the mix. Then subsequently do a formula to find minutes elapsed. I am not well versed in spreadsheet formulas so if there is an easier way of achieving my goal please let me know.

A screenshot is attached of the google sheet columns. Thank you to anyone that can help.

Screenshot of columns :

[image]

Comment: look at the function time in Excel.  Add 12 to the hour using an if statement when you have PM.  Assuming you can have someone time in at 23:00:00 and time out at 01:00:00 hours which is the next day, you will want to add 1 to the time if the time out is less than the time in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TIME(HOUR,MINUTES,SECONDS)
```

That is one formula that you can use to convert integers into time in excel.  I do not know if it will work in Google Sheets.  I will continue with the excel solution with the assumption the formulas are the same in google sheets or there is an equivalent.

Assuming your data is layed out as per the picture below, you could use the following formulas to convert your time to an actual time that the spreadsheet can use.  There are other solutions as well.

```
=TIME(A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0),B1,0)
```

That will convert your separated times into a spread sheet time.  Do the same thing for the OUT Time as below:

```
=TIME(D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0),E1,0)+IF(TIME(D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0),E1,0)<TIME(A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0),B1,0),1,0)
```

That whole other part about checking the time and adding 1 or 0 is that if the out time is less, it is assuming the time is the next day.  Days are represented by integers, and time is represented by the decimal value.

Now that you have a method for determine both times, subtract the larger time from the smaller time with the formula below in a single cell:

```
=(TIME(D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0),E1,0)+IF(TIME(D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0),E1,0)<TIME(A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0),B1,0),1,0))-(TIME(A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0),B1,0))
```

[image: POC]

## ALTERNATE METHOD

Convert everything to minutes, take the difference.

The first time converted to minutes will be:

```
=(A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0))*60+B1
```

The Second time converted to minutes will be:

```
=(D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0))*60+E1+IF(((D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0))*60+E1)<((A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0))*60+B1),24*60,0)
```

Now you just need to take the difference between the minutes in a single cell:

```
=((D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0))*60+E1+IF(((D1+IF(AND(F1="PM",D1<12),12,0))*60+E1)<((A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0))*60+B1),24*60,0))-((A1+IF(AND(C1="PM",A1<12),12,0))*60+B1)
```

[image: poc2]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much for explaining both ways. This isn't just an answer but an explanation I can use to learn. Thank you so so much.

Comment: FYI the the time limit is about 24 hours.  you would need to incorporate a date to your time stamp if you would looking at more than a 24 hour period between check in and out.

Comment: There is not need for more then 24 hours but thanks for the heads up

Comment: I have started using this on my timesheets and I noticed that when you  have a time in the 12 o'clock hour it calculates an extra 12 hours or 720 minutes. Here is your code being used:
`=((H11+IF(J11="PM",12,0))*60+I11+IF(((H11+IF(J11="PM",12,0))*60+I11)<((E11+IF(G11="PM",12,0))*60+F11),24*60,0))-((E11+IF(G11="PM",12,0))*60+F11)`

I have added a screenshot of the calculations to the main post. I am trying to figure it out but maybe thought you would have a quick fix. Thank you so much

Comment: What It is doing is adding 12 hours to anything that is marked as PM. Which is fine except if you have a time set like 12pm or 12:30pm. How do I stop it from adding the  12 hours to a 12 o'clock time.

Comment: I have a fix for this but I am currently busy doing an office move and wont be near a working computer till later.  Basically you need an AND with the PM and add a condition for hour to be less than 12.

Comment: Here is what I came up with: `=((H10+IF(J10="PM",12,0))*60+I10+IF(((H10+IF(J10="PM",12,0))*60+I10)<((E10+IF(G10="PM",12,0))*60+F10),24*60,0))-((E10+IF(G10="PM",12,0))*60+F10)-IF(E10=12,720,0)-IF(H10=12,720,0)+IF(AND(E10=12, H10=12), 1440, 0)`. Not sure if it is an elegant solution but i works. Let me know if you know of a better way of doing it or if I should stick with this. Good luck with your office move!

Comment: Glad you found a solution that worked for you.  I have updated the formulas in the solution above to include `AND( XX="PM",YY<12)` instead of just `XX="PM"`

Comment: That is much more elegant. Thank you very much!